# What is the issue with this C++ simple linked list implementation?

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list

This is a fairly simply project and I've spent probably about 20 hours on it traveling in a circle with no progress at all. I seemed to be heading in the right direction at the beginning but I had a TA try to explain it to me and it warped my brain putting me back at square one.

I know it's most likely a simple error so I will post code as well as my explanation. NOTE: Assert function is not an issue

IN H FILE

```
struct Node {
    int num;
    Node *next;
};
```

CPP File

```
void Intset::insert(int key)
{
   Node * current;
   current->num = key;
   current->next = NULL;
   assert (!find(key));
   if(head == NULL)
   {
      head = current;
   }
   else if(head->num >= key)
   {
      head->next = head;
      head = current;
   }
   else if(head->num < key)
   {
      head->next = current;
   }
```

So my thought process behind this function (insert key into a sorted linked list) is to create a new node current and fill its num field with the user entered key and have its next field equal to NULL. My first check is to see if head is empty and if it is copy the contents of current to it. My second check is to see if head's num field contains a number greater than or equal to the user entered key.

If so I move the head node to the next node and replace it with the current node (smaller number in front). My third check sees if the number in head is less than the user entered key and if so it fills head's next field with current (smaller number goes first). So far I've run into seg fault errors and I'm not sure what I am allocating incorrectly.

Comment: You need to declare the memory for new node. You can not simply insert it just like that.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Best way to figure out linked lists is with a pencil and paper. Draw out the nodes in the list. Draw in the connections between the nodes. Then redraw the list and any other involved nodes as you act on it, inserting and removing, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Start here:

```
Node * current;
current->num = key;
current->next = NULL;
```

Where does `current` point? You are dereferencing an un-initialized pointer. This is `undefined behavior` which could very well result in a seg fault.

Comment: Thanks Ben is the new function required here or should I just be consolidating into one line?

Comment: @Riossm, Im sorry, but based on my answer, that comment doesn't make sense to me, what do you mean?

Comment: ex. current = new Node(key, NULL);

Comment: @Riossm That is a start, yes, but make sure you read about `new` and `delete` and what they do, to make sure you don't cause memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks Ben I ended up using                                                           Node * current;
  current = new Node;
  current->num = key;
  current->next = NULL;

Comment: Also I was wondering how to go about asking questions since I've gotten so many downvotes. Do you have any tips, or is it just a terrible question? I really really tried to reference previous questions on stack.

Comment: @Riossm Read the [ask].

Comment: @Riossm: did not downvote, but my feedback here is that the question was a bit chatty and open-ended, and does not completely suit the style of specific and focussed questions we prefer here. You _might_ have had better luck at the _Code Review_ site, or if you would like a more forum/discussion-oriented site, Reddit is quite good.